# Temp DB full in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, tempdb

The issue is this: I have a wrapper stored procedure that contains a bunch of other stored procedures. It looks something like this:

```
Wrapper:

  exec procedure1
  exec procedure2
  exec procedure3
```

Each of the procedures creates a temp table that are used within it. The issue is that I run out of `tempDB` space every time I execute the wrapper.

However, while executing each individual stored procedure, it works fine.

My understanding is that the temp tables are dropped after the stored procedure is done. So why is my `tempDB` getting full?

edit:

This is the error i am getting.

> 1101 : Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? What error (code, message, etc.) information is provided?

Comment: @marc_s - eh? It's specifically documented that temp tables created within a stored procedure are dropped when the stored procedure returns

Comment: @marc_s - [`CREATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql#temporary-tables): "A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped automatically when the stored procedure is finished. The table can be referenced by any nested stored procedures..."

Comment: Does your wrapper and/or the individual stored procedure perform any explicit transaction management?

Comment: Why do you think that the problem is in any of temp tables? One can run out of tempdb when execute sort/aggregation. And it can be that your procs executed within wrapper just have different execution plans

Comment: This is the error i am getting. 1101 : Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

Comment: Will the temp table be dropped after each individual SP is finished or after the wrapper is finished?

Comment: Temp tables are "cached", that is they are not "totaly" dropped, 2 pages of every temp table is saved in cache. But these 2 pages cannot overflow your tempdb. So you can think that after every inner sp is finished, every #tmp table (not ##tmp!!!) is dropped

Comment: Why don't you seek your default trace to see if there are sort / hash spills that are always logged in the default trace?

Answer (score 1):

Running out of disk space in tempdb can cause disruption in the SQL Server environment.There could be various reasons for getting tempdb full like long execution of query, pumping alot of data in tempdb. You need to identify the reason of getting full tempdb. 
You can go through the following link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176029.aspx
This may help you out.